# How to show a background color over the full width when zooming in?

Tags: html, css, background, background-color

I want to show the background color of my header element over the full width of the browser window.

The following problem occurs: If the user zooms in or reduces the size of the browser window and when the vertical scroll bar appears, the background color of the header is not displayed over the full width of the page, it ends at the end of my header class.

Here you could see my code and the problem:

HTML

```
    <!doctype html>
<title>Funfighter Alliance</title>
<body>
    <!--Header mit Navigation-->
    <div id="header">
        <header>
            <!--Logo + Logounterschrift-->
                <h1><a href="http://funfighteralliance.de"><img alt="Funfighter Alliance - Offizielle Projekt-Homepage" src="/include/designs/FFA/bilder/Logo-FFA.jpg"></a></h1>

            <p>Offizielle Projekt-Homepage</p>
            <!--Navigation-->
            <nav>
                 <h2 class="hidden">Navigation</h2>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">News</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">Teams</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">Forum</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">Kontakt</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </div>
    <!--Spacer mit Log-In-->
    <section id="spacer">
         <h2 class="hidden">Log-In</h2>

        <div class="login">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
    /*Allgemeine Formatierungen für Elemente*/
 body {
    background:url(/include/designs/FFA/bilder/bg.png) repeat;
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    color:#272934;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border-top: 5px solid #009cff
}
p {
    margin: 5px 0;
    line-height:25px;
}
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:inherit;
    transition:color .5s ease;
}
strong {
    font-weight:bold;
}
img {
    height:auto;
    max-width:100%;
}
.hidden {
    position:absolute;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);
    /* IE6 & 7 */
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}
/*Spezielle Formatierungen für Klassen, Sektionen und Elemente*/

/*Header*/
 #header {
    background: red;
    width:auto;
}
header {
    position:relative;
    width:auto;
    max-width:1200px;
    margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
}
header h1 {
    margin: 35px 0 0 0;
}
header p {
    font-family:'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#6c6c6c;
    margin-left:74px;
}
/*Navigation*/
 nav {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
nav ul li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 3px 15px;
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please put the code in the question.

Comment: And get rid of the reset. JSFiddle uses it anyway, and we don't need to see it.

Comment: Done. In hope, that all is fine now with my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the JSFiddle at least, the problem seems to be occurring just because of this line:

```
<div class="login">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
```

Because there are no spaces in there, the browser wants to keep it all together on one line, which is messing up the layout.

You can see it because the red header div stretches 100% of the width with no white space to the right, no matter the size of the window, if you add `word-break:break-all;` to the `.login` class css.

Try adding this to your existing CSS and see if it helps the problem:

> .login {max-width: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
>
> #header {min-width: 100%;}

I realize the code you provided is an example, but it at least seems to fix the problem in the JSFiddle. Hope this helps.